VBA function FindInRow not always work - Find a cell in an excel row containing either text or date
Sometimes my VBA function FindInRow works, sometimes it doesn’t.
The VBA function FindInRow is used to find if a 'text' exists in an Excel row or not. If the text is found in the row, the function should return the column number where the text was found. If the text is not found, it should return 0.
Everything works fine - except when the searched text resembles a date. See my subroutine (TestFindInRow) which shows when it works and when it doesn't.
The text in the row is inserted using VBA from a string variable containing data that mostly, but not always resembles a date.
What could be the cause and what can I do to search for a string variable that resembles a date? And I want my function FindInRow to work both when the cells in the row contains either text or dates. Is there a solution?
Function FindInRow(ws As Worksheet, row As Long, s As String) As Long 'Return col

    Dim Cell As Range
    Set Cell = ws.Rows(row).Cells.Find(What:=s, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    If Cell Is Nothing Then
        FindInRow = 0
    Else
        FindInRow = Cell.Column
    End If

End Function

Sub TestFindInRow()

    Dim i As Integer
    Const sd As String = "2024-05-" 'Date ?
    Const ss As String = "XXXX-05-" 'String
    
    For i = 1 To 20
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i) = sd & i
    Next i
    
    'Test cell value type = Date ? > Not working
    Debug.Print FindInRow(ActiveSheet, 1, sd & 10)
    Debug.Print FindInRow(ActiveSheet, 1, sd & "10")

    For i = 1 To 20
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i) = ss & i
    Next i
    
    'Test cell value type = String > Working
    Debug.Print FindInRow(ActiveSheet, 1, ss & 10)
    Debug.Print FindInRow(ActiveSheet, 1, ss & "10")
    
End Sub


Are the worksheet "date" values you're trying to match on actual dates, or text that looks like a date?

If actual dates are on the sheet then you'd need (eg) FindInRow(ActiveSheet, 1, CDate(sd & "10"))

Well if they look like dates, they are actual dates, meaning they exist in the calendar. But they are inserted into the row as if they are text strings from a string variable. Sometime a row can contain only ‘date’ strings, sometime the text strings in the row can be alfanumeric.

If s looks like a date, then you can convert it to a date before passing it to Find(): otherwise, search for the supplied value:
Function FindInRow(ws As Worksheet, row As Long, s As String) As Long 'Return col
    Dim Cell As Range, v
    FindInRow = 0 'default return value
    v = s
    If IsDate(v) Then v = CDate(v) 'if looks like a date, convert to date
    Set Cell = ws.Rows(row).Cells.Find(What:=v, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not Cell Is Nothing Then FindInRow = Cell.Column
End Function

